# Multidimensional array, how do I solve this?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I've been trying to solve this, but I keep getting "gained" as output instead of user.

```
array(2) 
{ 
    ["SKILL"]=> array(2) 
    { 
         [0]=> array(2)
         { 
            ["user"]=> string(7) "USERNAME" ["gained"]=> int(15) 
         } 
         [1]=> array(2) 
         {
             ["user"]=> string(6) "USERNAME" ["gained"]=> int(8) 
         } 
         [2]=> array(2) 
         {
              ["user"]=> string(6) "USERNAME" ["gained"]=> int(3) 
         } 

    ["SKILL2"]=> array(2) 
    { 
        [0]=> array(2)
        {  
            ["user"]=> string(7) "USERNAME" ["gained"]=> int(10) 
        } 
        [1]=> array(2) 
        {
            ["user"]=> string(6) "USERNAME" ["gained"]=> int(7) 
        } 
        [2]=> array(2) 
        {
           ["user"]=> string(6) "USERNAME" ["gained"]=> int(5) 
       } 
}
```

I want it to output:

```
USERNAME ranked 1 gained 15<br/>
USERNAME ranked 2 gained 8<br/>
USERNAME ranked 3 gained 3<br/>
<br/><br/>
["SKILL2"]:<br/>
USERNAME ranked 1 gained 10<br/>
USERNAME ranked 2 gained 7<br/>
USERNAME ranked 3 gained 5<br/>
<br/><br/>
```

The array is sorted by "**gained**".
user ranked **$loopRuns** gained **$gained**

```
foreach($ar1 as $skill => $value)
{
    $i = 0;
    echo "<b>Skill: $skill</b><br/>";

    foreach($value as $ar2 => $ar3)
    {
        foreach($ar3 as $key => $value)
        {
            $i++;
                echo "$key Ranked #$i gained $value<br/>";
        }
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `var_export($ar1);` instead of the print_r result? Makes it easier to test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($skillArray as $skillName => $players)
{
  echo "skill: ".$skillName."<br/>";
  foreach($players as $rank => $data)
  {
    echo $data["user"]." ranked ".$rank." gained ".$data["gained"]." <br/>";
  }
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

**Explanation**

First loop will "visit" two main branches (`SKILL` and `SKILL1`). Those values (as they are array keys) are holded into `$skillName` variable, while whole player array, will be keep by `$players` variable.
Now you have to loop through every user. For do that, you write another `foreach` where keys will hold player position (ok, they are zero index, but if you want you can add a unit to it) and finally `data` will contain actually data.

Comment: Output:  SKILL0gained 581gained 152gained 2skill: SKILL20gained 1381gained 1272gained 126skill

Comment: it should output SKILL USER #1 gained X, not SKILL(userIndex) gained skill, thanks

Answer (score 0):

How abount using fieldsets and legends?

Code:

```
<?php

$skills = array(
    'SKILL' => array(
        array(
            'user'   => 'USERNAME',
            'gained' => 15        ,
        ),
        array(
            'user'   => 'USERNAME',
            'gained' => 8         ,
        ),
        array(
            'user'   => 'USERNAME',
            'gained' => 3         ,
        ),
    ),
    'SKILL2' => array(
        array(
            'user'   => 'USERNAME',
            'gained' => 10        ,
        ),
        array(
            'user'   => 'USERNAME',
            'gained' => 7         ,
        ),
        array(
            'user'   => 'USERNAME',
            'gained' => 5         ,
        ),
    ),
);


foreach ($skills as $skill => $users) {

    echo "<fieldset>\n";
    echo "<legend>{$skill}</legend>\n";
    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
        printf("%s ranked %d gained %d<br />\n",
            $user['user']  ,
            $key + 1       ,
            $user['gained']
        );
    }
    echo "</fieldset>\n";

}
```

Output:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>SKILL</legend>
USERNAME ranked 1 gained 15<br />
USERNAME ranked 2 gained 8<br />
USERNAME ranked 3 gained 3<br />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>SKILL2</legend>
USERNAME ranked 1 gained 10<br />
USERNAME ranked 2 gained 7<br />
USERNAME ranked 3 gained 5<br />
</fieldset>
```

View:
[image: View]